# Is there any way to save background images in the .blend file?

Tags: blend-files, image

I'm trying to use the background images option to model from blueprints.  After I cropped, loaded, positioned and scaled in each viewport, things were going pretty well with the modeling.  I saved the progress on the model and came back the next day and the images were not there.  Am I missing something?  Do I have to set everything else up again or do you have to get your modeling done in one session?

Comment: Just wondering if you moved the blend file after saving. Otherwise Blender should be able to load the images.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The most convenient way**

> File -> External Data -> Pack into .blend

In the report area it will say `'n files packed'` Where n is the amount of images currently in the image list. Now hitting save will include those images in the .blend.
The problem you might have with this method is that it will auto-pack any subsequent images you add.

**Alternatively (one by one, gives more control)**
You do them individually, go to the UV image editor. For each image you want to pack you select the image so it shows in the view, then

> Image > Pack Image

Again **you have to save the .blend file** before exiting.

**Further reading**
Obligitory [Blender Wiki link: *Pack and Unpack Data*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Data_System#Pack_and_Unpack_Data), it's an interesting read.

Comment: This solution did exactly what I had hoped it would.  I knew Blender had to be able to do this.  Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: @user809 take your time before accepting, you might get more complete answers, it's worth reading through all of them to make sense of the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing exactly what you did to lose the images, I guess it is ok to share this tip as well, [zeffii](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1337/12) is right that packing is more convenient but packing images ***will*** increase your file size, more so if you have several and or they are large in size.

With regards to [satishgoda's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/is-there-any-way-to-save-background-images-in-the-blend-file#comment2293_1336) above, you wouldn't normally *want* to pack blueprints with your model. So, while it *is* what you asked for, based on your question, I can tell it isn't what you actually need. You can press the *F* next to the image(s) and save as you would normally. Checking this makes sure that they don't get removed even when they have no users *(when they show up with a 0 beside their name which happens when you don't have the image in use)*, so as long as you haven't moved the file, you should be ok.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem you're having is actually not related to saving the images, but instead having to do with how you're trying to view them. Background images only show up when you're in Orthographic mode, and using one of the preset view angles (Top, Side, Front, etc).

To toggle in and out of Orthographic mode, press <kbd>numpad 5</kbd>. The shortcuts for the preset views are the other numpad keys (Top = <kbd>numpad 7</kbd>, Side = <kbd>numpad 1</kbd>, Front = <kbd>numpad 3</kbd>).