# Object turning grey in rendered view

Tags: rendering, animation, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, light

My sword looks fine in solid view, but when I go into rendered view, it turns completely grey.

I have mipmaps off, texture solid on and i have light.

It looks fine in solid view:

[image: intended coloring];

But when I switch to rendered view, the sword is entirely grey.

[image: rendered coloring].

Link to file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36878
Link to Sword: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36888

Comment: Materials? UV maps? What have you checked?

Comment: i just linked the sword with texture in this file with a minecraft_rig and connected it to the right hand bone but when i go in rendered view it turns grey. I dont know why but i can tell you that i used UV image to add the texture to sword and did not touch materials.

Comment: The sword is only illuminated on the other side, as the sun lamp appears to be pointing slightly towards the camera. Try adding another lamp or some environment lighting in *Properties > World*.

Comment: i tried putting the camera in a corner but no difference :/ and the lighting in the properties > world makes the sword completely white :/

Comment: The sword still appears grey on the other side? Is it possible you could upload your .blend or a screenshot of your sword material settings?

Comment: Please consider [packing textures](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1337/1245) into your file and uploading it to [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend) or [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: I downloaded the file you linked to in order to try to help, but I got an error; apparently the sword is in a different file.

Comment: Same here. No sword...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sword doesn't have a material assigned to it.
Create one and create a texture that uses the image using your UV mapping.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to smooth the texture of sword? i can see in render mode its still kinda blurish or how do you call it.

Comment: try using a larger image. Yours is only 16x16 pixels.

Comment: i used the picture from minecraft folders but i cant find any other bigger picture, maybe if i can get another example of a sword image to use?