# Problems with Weight Transfer to Shirt Objects

Tags: texturing, objects, cloth-simulation

[image]

I have a shirt draped on a human body. The shirt appears fine in the texture mode with the texture applied, but it appears totally black in the solid view and the edit view. I tried recalculating and flipping the normals. That did not help. Scale and rotation are applied on the object, so no problem there as well. This is problem number one.

Problem number two occurred when I was trying to transfer weights of the armature from human body to the shirt on the body. I tried to transfer weights and I could not see that happening on the shirt. The shirt stays still when I move the arms or body.

Here is the .blend file

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately images [aren't packed](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/is-there-any-way-to-save-background-images-in-the-blend-file) into the file, but in the file GLSL shadiing mode along with `Textured Solid` option are turned on. This means textures will be shown when in Solid mode too. Probably that means you see black texture in your case.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. Texture is not so important for me at this point, but rigging cloth is. Can you please see what can be done to transfer weights from body to shirt?

Comment: Problem with texture was included as a part of the question. I'd like to mention that you'll likely get more clear answers if asking one question per time. You can link one to another if that helps providing context.

Answer (score 2):

In solid mode, Only the viewport color is taken into consideration.
The viewport color has no effect on the textures or final render output.
It's use and purpose is purely for differentiating objects from one
another in a crowded scene, when using "solid" mode rendering in the
viewport.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I see the behaviour a little random here. I saved the file and then reopened to see the file opening fine, with the object not appearing black in the solid mode. I need to check again why exactly this is happening.

Comment: Okay here is the problem. I am trying to transfer weights from body to the shirt for the underlying armature. So I am first selecting the shirt and then the body armature and I'm doing Set Parent to - Armature Deform - With Empty Groups and then I deselect everything, Select the body, and the shirt and go to the weight painting mode. Now I see the shirt all black. When I click transfer weights, I see nothing happening. If I save it and reopen the file, I dont see the blackness anymore but weights get assigned randomly to the shirt and the movement is not as expected.

Comment: Would it be fine if you upload the .blend file so we can reproduce the problem described?

Comment: Here is the blend file.
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=849" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/849/)

Comment: @Sum-Al you should add the link on your original post, and probably change you title to "Problems with Transfering Weights to Shirt Object". I do not have enough experience with the problem you are encountering ... you will have to wait for someone who has some clue to what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. Textures do not show unless you are in textured or viewport render. you can can check by switching to viewport render by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at any time to see your results
You'll also want to ensue that you have adequate lighting in your scene.