# UV Seams and Unwrapping Complications

Tags: uv, modifiers, mirror

I'm new to blender and the process of creating seams and unwrapping them has been a challenge. I made this chair with the mirrored modifier, applied it, and then tried to texture it by marking seams and UV unwrapping.

Because my seams looked terrible I went under Mesh>UV Unwrap and reset everything and got the image below. While it looks better than what I had, I now am particularly concerned by the obvious tear down the middle of the chair where you can clearly see where the mirror modifier was applied. It seems to be effecting my texturing as well?

I'm not sure I'm using the right words to describe my predicament, but I'm wanting my chair to look like a chair, but I think I ran into a problem with my mirror modifier. Help?[image]

Comment: If you unwrapped *before* applying modifier, then the seam in the middle is visible because half of UV map was rotated and half probably left as is. If it was unwrapped *after* then I think it was unwrapped in such way that it's visible now. In order to solve your particular case it's best to upload your file [on dedicated site](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) with [packed images](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1336/1245)