# Cannot see background image after reopening the blender file

Tags: blend-files

[image]

I after reopening by blender file I cannot see the placed background image. You can see the screen capture for reference. I made sure I am not in perspective view, but that does not help. I would appreciate any help on this subject.

Comment: Make sure that the .blend file wasn't moved from directory where it was saved, and that image used as background wasn't moved / deleted. You might want to pack background images, see related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/is-there-any-way-to-save-background-images-in-the-blend-file

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I had changed the location of the blender file.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44225/why-is-that-when-i-open-up-my-file-in-blender-the-reference-picture-is-gone

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your files are in the same directory as when they were first added.