# Why won't the textures render even though they seem appear to be in the texture panel correctly?

Tags: rendering, texturing

Okay I am very new at this. I am trying to export some 3D models from a game, and when I load the model (the model and textures are in the same folder) the textures automatically load. In texture mode they show up properly, but when I use "Render Image" it is just a square blob and when the "OpenGL Image Render" is used it is just a white colored version of the model.

I am not sure if there is any other details that might be needed, since I am very new at this. I am not sure if there is any specific images or anything that might be wanted. Any help that can be provided is appreciated.

Update:
Here is a link to the file: [image]

Also it seems that materials were automatically created when the file was imported. I did add some lamps, but the textures still didn't rendered.

Update again: I have changed the link and I think I did it right to pack the other files in the blend.

Update again: Here is a new blend file with the model extracted again. [image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots or upload the file [Here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Have you created proper materials after importing?

Comment: maybe lighting of your Blender scene is different?

Comment: I have added a link to the file in the original post. I did add lamps, but the textures didn't render. It appeared that materials were automatically created when the file was imported.

Comment: Downloaded your blend... looks like you have multiple .png textures referenced, but none of them seem to be in the .blend file. You may need to pack them before uploading your blend. Also, it seems the scale of your armature/figure is very large and the saved location of your camera was inside the left shoe.

Comment: How do I pack them in the blend then?

Comment: @LadyAriel : See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/is-there-any-way-to-save-background-images-in-the-blend-file/1337#1337

Comment: @Mike Metcalf : I have updated the file above and it should have the packed files included

Comment: @LadyAriel : Okay... Lots of issues. Don't have a good answer for you. But this is what I did: Switched to Cycles renderer (combo box, top center). Then selected each body part in turn in object mode. In the Properties, Materials panel, hit the 'Use Nodes' button. In the Node Editor, added a 'Texture, Image Texture' node and set the image to one of your .png files. Once all pieces were done, the 3D Window shows the model properly textured in 'Texture', 'Material' and 'Rendered' mode. BUT: the actual render is still hosed. Even when I move the camera out of the foot. I don't know why.

Comment: @Mike Metcalf : What do you mean by the actual render is hosed? And do you know of any other reasons that might cause this?

Not sure if when I exported the model and selected the "retain animation if supported" might of caused anything or not.

Comment: The actual render, when you hit F12, or go to the menu item 'Render' and click 'Render Image' will render the scene normally. The other render views I mentioned above are various render previews.  I suggest you export again from your source and reimport into a clean blender file.

Comment: @Mike Metcalf : I have uploaded a new blend file with a newly extracted model from the source.

Comment: @LadyAriel  Did anything change? Does it now render?

Comment: Ok, good news. The new .blend is much better. You need to do a few things, tho...  First: select the armature in Object mode (not Edit mode, and not in Pose mode) and scale it down to 10% its original size (Select it, hit 'S', then '0.1', then enter). Next, move the camera from its default location and point it toward your figure. Move the lamp so it is illuminating the front of the figure. Hit render. Should work.

Comment: @Mike Metcalf : Thanks for that. I can't figure out where to put the light and camera (either her head is cut off or her feet, and half of it is dark). I did scale it down (I think it was object mode, but not completely sure since I am not sure which mode is which).

Comment: Also is there a easy way to turn the figure around so it faces forward and not sideways?

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos  -and- cegaton -and- someonewithpc -and- iKlsR:  This question is about the user exporting from a game and importing into blender. The question you reference seems to be the about exporting FROM blender. That seems to be a significant difference.

Comment: @Mike Metcalf : How do you turn the model around so it faces forward instead of to the side?

Comment: @MikeMetcalf There is absolutely no difference, the same base rule applies: Materials are for the most part not exportable (with some exceptions).